# Scope of Java static member in web applications

Tags: java, static

Are Java static variables shared across instances of the same web application?

```
class MyClass
{
    private static SomeClass myStaticObject = new SomeClass();
}
```

If a web application uses **MyClass** and multiple instances of that application is run on a web server, is **myStaticObject** initialized multiple times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically, yes. Most containers will provide separate classloaders for each web application. This will result in the class being loaded multiple times when used by several applications, and thus resulting in multiple instances of the static variable.

Stating the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html) for reference:

> At run time, several reference types
>   with the same binary name may be
>   loaded simultaneously by different
>   class loaders. These types may or may
>   not represent the same type
>   declaration. Even if two such types do
>   represent the same type declaration,
>   they are considered distinct.

By inference, multiple instances of static variables will exist, unless the classes are loaded only once by a parent class loader, and never loaded elsewhere by any other class loader.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite see the point of having a `private static` variable in `MyClass`. If it's `private` you cannot access it as a class variable from outside the class you defined it in. If you just want other classes to access this variable via a getter method you should remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: There are plenty of use-cases of using a `private static` variable. One such is to hold the next available object ID.