# Counting error when using application in jsp

Tags: jsp

I tried to use application object to record how many visitors have viewed this page,but after I refreshed the page I closed the browser,and when I open the browser again to view this page,the record back to the number I started to refresh.I don't know why?

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <%
            Integer count;
            synchronized (application) {
                count = (Integer) application.getAttribute("count");
                if(count == null)
                    count = new Integer(0);
                count = new Integer(count.intValue() + 1);
                application.setAttribute("count", count);
            }
        %>
        This page has been visited <%= count.intValue() %> times！
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have synchronized? Why dont you just use a global variable (ie java `static`)?

You don't have to worry about threads on the web-server.  It should handle that.

A global variable on the server will be the same for all threads.

Sample here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_hits_counter.htm

which says to use :

```
application.setAttribute(String Key, Object Value);
```

then get it with ..

```
application.getAttribute(String Key);
```

An example:

```
<%
    Integer hitsCount = (Integer)application.getAttribute("hitCounter");
    if( hitsCount ==null || hitsCount == 0 ){
       /* First visit */
       out.println("Welcome to my website!");
       hitsCount = 1;
    }else{
       /* return visit */
       out.println("Welcome back to my website!");
       hitsCount += 1;
    }
    application.setAttribute("hitCounter", hitsCount);
%>
```

with

```
<p>Total number of visits: <%= hitsCount%></p>
```

Comment: Static variables are SO BAD in  Java Web Applications, they will live until your JVM (in this case, your web application server) is stopped. Plus, this code looks almost exactly what he has done.

Comment: I compared my code with yours,I didn't found too much difference.But I noticed this "application.setAttribute(String Key, Object Value);",so I change my key to "counter",makes it different from the value,and it works.It is so strange.This error has nothing to do with the "synchronized",though "synchronized" is not necessary.

Comment: @Luggi, they are useful.  I have a huge dictionary library that takes 3-9 seconds to decode.  So, loading it only the first time and having it accessible for all clients is useful IMO.  If you mean having sensitive information static, then I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some kind of framework with a controller you can also you a `public static Integer count` on the controller side that increments the count by 1 each time the handler method is called and puts the count in the model for that page.

Comment: [Static variables in Java web application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6389337/1065197) are not a good idea.

Comment: I am just a beginner,and this is just a simple sample.